# Why does this Python class code cause a syntax error?

Tags: python, class

```
class Song(object):

def _init_(self, lyrics):
   self.lyrics = lyrics

def sing_me_a_song(self):
    for line in self.lyrics:
        print line


happy_bday = Song(["heyhey","hey"])

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around the family","hey"])

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()
```

Hi I'm learning python using learnpythonthehardway. I am getting error in this code and unable to figure out my mistake. Please guide me , i'm a beginner in Python

Comment: Please mention the error!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you missed the indentation, it is possible that the problem occurred at the time of copy the code to stack overflow. So, i am ignoring these problems.

So, let's fix indentation and run your code.

```
class Song(object):

    def _init_(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
        print line


    happy_bday = Song(["heyhey","hey"])

    bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around the family","hey"])

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ahsanul/Downloads/PythonThreads/threading2.py", line 26, in <module>
happy_bday = Song(["heyhey","hey"])
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

So, the main problem you have is defining the `__init__` . You are writing `_init_` instead of `__init__`. If you know the purpose of it, the problem would become clear to you.

`__init__` is called when a class object is initialized. By writing `__init__` inside your class, you will actually overriding the default one.

So, you have added a parameter `lyrics` in your `_init_` so that you can pass an argument at the time of object initialization, right?

But your function would never be called, that because `__init__` is called at the time of initialization, not `_init_`

So, the default `__init__` will be called every time, which has no parameter and at the time of object initialization, you always get an error.

Just change your `_init_` to `__init__` and you will listen the sweet little song like me.

```
heyhey
hey
They rally around the family
hey
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing indentation inside the class.

And you need to defined method `__init__`, not `_init_`.

```
class Song(object):
    def __init__(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print line
```

Python is sensitive to indentation.